# DBIx::Class and overloading accessors

Tags: perl, dbix-class

(Similar to, but with more concrete details that, [#11526999](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526999/dbixclass-wrapping-overloading-a-column-accessor))

My Result Classes have been built using `dbicdump`, however I wish to overload the default accessor for a `date` field.

### Works, but a bodge

To *hackytest* my idea, I simply added an `accessor` attribute to the created `date` key of the `add_columns` call:

```
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  "stamp_id",
  {
    data_type         => "integer",
    is_auto_increment => 1,
    is_nullable       => 0,
    sequence          => "timestamp_stamp_id_seq",
  },
  "date",
  { data_type => "date", is_nullable => 0, accessor => '_date' },
);
```

... and created my accessor routine below the Schema::Loader checksum line:

```
# DO NOT MODIFY THIS OR ANYTHING ABOVE! md5sum:nB5koMYAhBwz4ET77Q8qlA

sub date {
  my $self = shift;
  warn "overloaded date\n"; # Added for debugging
  my $date;

  # The date needs to be just the date, not the time
  if ( @_ ) {
    $date = shift;
    if ( $date =~ /^([\d\-]+)/ ) {
      $date = $1
    }
    return $self->_date($date)
  }

  # Fetch the column value & remove the time part.
  $date = $self->_date;
  if ( $date =~ /^([\d\-]+)/ ) {
      $date = $1
  }

  return $date;
}
```

This works, as it returns an expected `2014-10-04`, but is a bodge.

### Do it the right way

The problem is that I've hacked the checksum'd code, so I can't neatly re-generate my Class objects.

Reading [ResultSource](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSource#accessor) and the [CookBook](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Manual::Cookbook#Wrapping-overloading-a-column-accessor) the correct approach appears to be:

Have the ResultSource built by `dbicdump` as standard:

```
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  "stamp_id",
  {
    data_type         => "integer",
    is_auto_increment => 1,
    is_nullable       => 0,
    sequence          => "timestamp_stamp_id_seq",
  },
  "date",
  { data_type => "date", is_nullable => 0 },
);
```

.... add a *change the accessor* **below the line**, using the `+` to indicate it's an alteration to an existing definition:

```
# DO NOT MODIFY THIS OR ANYTHING ABOVE! md5sum:nB5koMYAhBwz4ET77Q8qlA

__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  "+date", { accessor => '_date' },
);
```

.... use the overload method as before

### Not working.

I've double-checked my spelling, I've tried `add_column` rather than `add_columns`, and I've tried putting the second `add_columns` to directly below the first - all to now avail.... the code uses the default accessor, and returns `2014-10-04T00:00:00`

How do I over-ride the default accessor, so I can use my own method?

Thankee...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here is a [col_accessor_map](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::Base#col_accessor_map) passed in as a loader option.

```
col_accessor_map => {
  table_name => {
    date => _date,
  }
}
```

You can pass loader options to [dbicdump](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader/script/dbicdump) with `-o`.

```
$ dbicdump -o col_accessor_map="{ table_name => { date => _date } }" ... other options ...
```

(Replace `table_name` above with the name of your table - that's obvious, right?)

**Update:** This was posted untested, and when I finally got round to testing it, I found it didn't work. After a conversation with [the author](https://metacpan.org/author/ILMARI) on IRC I was told that the `col_accessor_map` option doesn't support this nested hash approach, so if you wanted to use this approach you would need to use a coderef.

However, the author also agreed that adding this support would be a good idea and I've just got back from lunch to find this [Github commit](https://github.com/dbsrgits/dbix-class-schema-loader/commit/3a7a1d7726d84d0970d8ff8e8107fc52e3af0f53) which adds the feature. I don't know how soon it will get to CPAN though.

This may be the first time that CPAN has been updated to make a SO answer correct :-)

Comment: is there something wrong with the approach I was using?

The documentation seems to imply it's the right path...

Comment: I can't see anything in the documentation which implies that your `add_columns("+date" ...)` syntax will work.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Manual::Cookbook#Wrapping-overloading-a-column-accessor describes using the accessor overload and the third paragraph of https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSource#add_columns refers to `('+col1')` - I added the two together, and assumed I could append that syntax to a ResultSource package

Comment: You're right. Let me have a look and see if I can work out what the problem is.

Comment: Upgraded `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader` to 0.07044 (or later) to get the `col_accessor_map` functionality. Then adding `-o col_accessor_map="{ table_name => { date => '_date' } }"` to the command line (and note the quotes around the `_date` - essential!)

Comment: Yeah. Here's the commit that fixed the problem - https://github.com/dbsrgits/dbix-class-schema-loader/commit/3a7a1d7726d84d0970d8ff8e8107fc52e3af0f53

Answer (score 0):

At a different level of abstraction I believe you could use a method modifier

```
use Class::Method::Modifier; # or Moose/Moo
around date => sub {...};
```